# iterate dirs using filemanager take up quite a lot memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, nsfilemanager

i'm using `NSFileManager`'s `enumeratorAtPath` method to calculate file size under certain dir.

```
NSString *iterDir = @"/path/to/dir/";
NSFileManager *fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnum = [fm enumeratorAtPath:iterDir];

NSString *file;
BOOL isDir;
long long fileSize = 0;
while (file = [dirEnum nextObject]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        file = [iterDir stringByAppendingString:file];
        if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:file isDirectory:&isDir]) {
            if (!isDir) {
                NSError *error;
                NSDictionary *attributes = [fm attributesOfItemAtPath:file error:&error];
                if (!error) {
                    fileSize += [attributes[@"NSFileSize"] doubleValue];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
NSLog(@"fileSize:%lld", fileSize);
```

the result is like this:

[image: take many memory during while loop]

sometimes like this:

[image: no returning memory]

what are the memory used for? why even add a `@autoreleasepool` outside takes no effect?

Comment: Find out what's causing it using Instruments. Then report back here because I'm curious.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't make your example run as provided, even by substituting a valid directory path. Your code has a few problems. Here's a couple of changes you need to make. One is this line:

```
file = [iterDir stringByAppendingString:file];
```

which really ought to be changed to:

```
file = [iterDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
```

The latter is much, much safer because it will correctly append the path regardless of whether your directory path ends with a `/` or not. (Your original failed in my case, since I used `[@"~/Desktop" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]` to get my directory path; that yields a path with no trailing `/`.)

Then inside your loop, you're allocating an uninitialized variable `error` on the stack, passing it by reference, and then asking if it's `nil`. That's the wrong question to ask, because the value of `error` isn't guaranteed unless the method returns nil (or `NO`, depending on the method). You should instead ask if `attributes` is `nil`, and pass `NULL` for `error`, since you don't otherwise seem to be interested in it. So to sum up, change this:

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *attributes = [fm attributesOfItemAtPath:file error:&error];
if (!error) {
```

to this:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [fm attributesOfItemAtPath:file error:NULL];
if (attributes != nil) {
```

Fixing that second issue means your results will be more consistent, I promise. Meanwhile, I'm getting a result that looks like it might be a valid value in the `NSLog()` statement when I run the code.

Apropos of nothing, you can also use fast enumeration for your loop. Instead of:

```
while (file = [dirEnum nextObject]) {
```

you could instead use:

```
for (file in dirEnum) {
```

Now for your original question. The reason your allocated memory is bulking up is that your strings containing the file names are allocated outside the scope of your `@autoreleasepool` directive into the main autorelease pool, where they'll just sit until that pool empties. You've still done a good thing using your own autorelease pool inside the loop, however.

Comment: thanks 4 ur optimize advice, they are really helpful. but still can't fix / explain the memory problem. can't run? you can provide absolute path like `/Users/yourname/Desktop`. it should do the work.

Comment: An absolute path would work, but what about when other means are used that produce a path without a trailing slash, such as what I used?

Comment: of course `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` works, but no effect to the result.